# ImageButton shows random images

Tags: android

Hi i have a problem while creating imageview when i click previous(b1) and next(b2) button it shows next and previous images from img array but sometimes it shows random images like android layout images etc.

```
public class FullTable extends Activity{
  int[] img={
         R.drawable.t1,R.drawable.t2,R.drawable.t3,
         R.drawable.t4,R.drawable.t5,R.drawable.t6,
         R.drawable.t7,R.drawable.t8,R.drawable.t9,
         R.drawable.t10,R.drawable.t11,R.drawable.t12,
         R.drawable.t13,R.drawable.t14,R.drawable.t15,
         R.drawable.t16,R.drawable.t17,R.drawable.t18,
         R.drawable.t19,R.drawable.t20};
 ImageButton b1,b2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_table);
        b1 =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonback);
        b2=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent(); 
        // Selected image id
        final int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        //imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setImageResource(img[position]);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                imageView.setImageResource(img[position]-1);
                img[position]--;

            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                imageView.setImageResource(img[position]+1);
                img[position]++;


            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Use Iterator for this.

Comment: Do want to show images randomly, or in a sequence on previous and next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your code you're not incrementing and decrementing your `position` variable at all. And your logic seems somewhat wrong. That's why you're getting some random IDs.

If you already have your `img` array with the `Drawable`s IDs you want, you can simply set your `position` variable to zero and remove the `final` from it, and then increment it and decrement it directly.

For example, change this:

```
img[position]--;
```

To this:

```
img[--position];
```

And set:

```
int position = 0; // Default value.
```

Later, change the method [`ImageView#setImageResource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) to [`ImageView#setImageDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)). Like:

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(img[position]); // Get the Drawable Object.

imageview.setImageDrawable(myDrawable); // Set the Drawable on your ImageView.
```

Also, consider using a `List` like `ArrayList` instead of a simple array.

---

**EDIT:** As you asked on the comments, you can start over again by reseting your `position` variable to zero if you're on the last image. You can do that by getting the `length` of the array. Something like:

```
if (position >= img.length) {
    position = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem one more question in the end of list it shows indexoutofbound exception i want list to startover again please help

Comment: You can reset your `position` variable after it reaches the end to start over. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `onClick()` for `b1`:
`imageView.setImageResource(img[position]-1);`: this line of code is getting the `id` of `drawables` from `img` array and decreasing that value by `1`.
But what you want is to display previous image so you need to modify your code to:

```
imageView.setImageResource(img[**position-1**]); 
similary modify your code for b2 onCLick
imageView.setImageResource(img[**position+1**]);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a variable `position` at `class scope` and not inside `onCreate()` method. then in your b1 `onClick()` method decrement `position` and then show image, posting some code to demonstrate the same: ->

```
// at class level and not inside `onCreate()`
ImageButton b1,b2;
int position = 0; // Initializing with default value

// then inside onCreate()

position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position--;

            if(position < 0){
               position = img.length;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(img[position]);

        }
    });
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position++;

            if(position > img.length - 1){
               position = 0;
            }
            imageView.setImageResource(img[position]);

        }
    });
```